# How to return a Singleton from a getter function using Koin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I have the following `CurrentWeatherResponse` class which contains the `location` field that uses a getter to return an instance of `WeatherLocation()` using the class's constructor params. How would i go about making sure that this getter will always return a singleton of the `WeatherLocation` class using Koin in a module file?

```
data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
    // Tells GSON that the "currently" field of the JSON returned by the
    // API should be tied with our CurrentWeatherEntry data class
    @SerializedName("currently")
    val currentWeatherEntry: CurrentWeatherEntry,
    val latitude:Double,
    val longitude:Double,
    val timezone:String
) {
    val location:WeatherLocation
        get() = WeatherLocation(latitude,longitude,timezone,currentWeatherEntry.time)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using delegates. It's simple class:

```
class ReadOnlyDelegate<R, T>(val t:T) : ReadOnlyProperty<R, T> {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>) = t
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
    // Tells GSON that the "currently" field of the JSON returned by the
    // API should be tied with our CurrentWeatherEntry data class
    @SerializedName("currently")
    val currentWeatherEntry: CurrentWeatherEntry,
    val latitude:Double,
    val longitude:Double,
    val timezone:String) {

    val location:WeatherLocation by ReadOnlyDelegate(WeatherLocation(latitude, longitude, timezone, currentWeatherEntry.time))
}
```